# How to decode a list of letters and rebuild the original word in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to make a makeshift encoder/decoder without the use of modules and well my method works with singular letters but not words. I have the code set up so it encodes every letter of the word with a key you choose.

What I'm wondering is how can you decode a list of encoded numbers one by one and then rebuild the word. This would be amazing and very helpful thanks.
P.S. I'm a beginner in Python and this is my second day so I tried everything I know also please don't use any modules.

```
while True :
option = input('Encode or Decode? : ')
if option == 'encode':
    start = input('What word do you want to be encoded?: ')
    word = start
    key = int(input('What key would you like to use?: '))
    z=[]
    for i in word:
        encoder = ord(i)*key+key/key
        z.append(encoder)
    print(z)
else:
    start = float(input('What encoded string do you want to be decoded?: '))
    key = int(input('What key would you like to use?: '))
    decoder = start/key
    print(chr(round(decoder)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do to decode is to type the sequence of numbers back into the code I have adjusted for you:

```
else:
    x = []
    start = (input('What encoded nubmers do you want to be decoded?: '))
    split_list = start.split()
    key = int(input('What key would you like to use?: '))
    for i in split_list:
        integer = int(i)
        decoder = int(integer/key)
        letter = chr(decoder)
        x.append(letter)
    print("".join(x))
```

`start.split()` splits the code into separate strings and puts them in a list, `split_list`. The code then checks every number in `split_list` and decodes the number, then turns it back into a character. It then prints the joined result of the characters.

For example, if I encode `apple` with key `5`, then run the decoder and type `486 561 561 541 506` with key `5` it successfully returns `apple`.

This even works for multiple words, as I tried encoding `hello world` then decoding it and it was successful. I hope this helps! :)

Comment: This was very  useful though to make it work I had to change some of the encoding part to fit with the decoder, anyways thanks!